# Apache CXF - validation of generated classes before sending to the API (in backing bean or where?)

Tags: apache, validation, xsd, jaxb, cxf

I have one question. I am using Apache CXF framework to generate model classes from xsd. It works ok but now I have large CSV file used for model with a lot of attributes (around 20) and I want to validate every of this atrributes before sending them to some api method (saving to a database). Exists there some way how could I do it in my backing bean? Or somewhere else? I did not find any tutorial or example...

Comment: Do you need JAXB to validate the generated XML? Have you checked `javax.xml.bind.Marshaller#setSchema()` then?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It looks helpful. Is it possible to use for me when I work with Jersey framework (Apache CXF was not really good) so I send JAXB object to REST api this way:

Comment: ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/xml").post(ClientResponse.class, object); ...now how can I validate with javax.xml.bind.Marshaller#setSchema() as you said please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [How can I turn on schema validation for jaxws endpoint](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIturnonschemavalidationforjaxwsendpoint%3F):

```
<jaxws:client name="{http://apache.org/serivce}SoapPort" createdFromAPI="true">
  <jaxws:properties>
    <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
  </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:client>
```

Comment: Thanks again, unfortunately I switched from Apache CXF to Jersey and this piece of code is for Apache CXF framework... I must find something else for Jersey.